# jQuery button background slide in/up effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quick question guys - what would be the best method to achieve effect like below? I want the exact shape of a button, but in different colour, to slide in from the bottom. I currently have the button on pure CSS, can I keep it that way (preferred) or do I need to make the button a sprite gfx and just animate background position?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `:before` pseudo-selector like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">Send</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    width:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.button a{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
.button:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:orange;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    transition:all 1s;
}
.button:hover:before {
    top:0;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8292/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with pure CSS:

```
.button {
  width: 200px; height: 100px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, orange 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}

.button {
  background-position: 0 +100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P6Jx7/

Comment: wow, nice and simple. only one small problem - what slides in is a straight line, without rounded corners (that's what I meant by keeping the exact shape). Any way to do it with keeping the rounded corners ?